# ReferenceError: Cannot find fixture 'spec/fixtures/<my-component></my-component>' at <Jasmine>

Tags: html, jasmine, karma-jasmine, web-component, fixtures

I have a very basic vanilla webcomponents and I have been studing how properly unit test it. As the most basic test I just want to test if I can find a div on it.

I am trying to use karma-fixture. Honestly, I though I could use fixture straigh forward since I had Jasmine dependency but based on error I got It seems I must include an explicit fixture dependency so I tried [karma-fixture](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-fixture)

Before I added karma-fixture I got

```
ReferenceError: fixture is not defined
            at <Jasmine>
            at UserContext.<anonymous> (test/my-component.test-without-openwc.js:19:16)
            at <Jasmine>
```

After I added karma-fixture now I get the error pasted in this question topic

```
 ReferenceError: Cannot find fixture 'spec/fixtures/<my-component></my-component>'
at <Jasmine>
at Fixture._throwNoFixture (node_modules/karma-fixture/lib/fixture.js:141:13)
at Fixture.load (node_modules/karma-fixture/lib/fixture.js:78:18)
at UserContext.<anonymous> (test/my-component.test-without-openwc.js:20:30)
at <Jasmine>
```

I don't know whatelse I can try. My straigh question is: why I am getting this error? Surronded doubts very usefull are:

1 - isn't jasmine dependency enough for use fixture?
2 - can I use fixture for loanding my vanilla webcomponent and then check if I can find certain tag?

Vanilla Webcomponent which I want to check if there is a

```
const templateString = `<div id="mydiv" name="mydiv"><p>Hello world 2!</p></div>`;
const template = document.createElement("template");
template.innerHTML = templateString;

export class MyComponent extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
    shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
  }
}
customElements.define("my-component", MyComponent);
```

karma.conf.js

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: "",
    frameworks: ["fixture","jasmine"],
    files: [
      "node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-bundle.js",
      {
        pattern: "**/*.test-without-openwc.js",
        type: "module",
        included: true
      },
      { pattern: "**/*.js", type: "module", included: false }
    ],
    exclude: [],
    preprocessors: {},
    reporters: ["spec"],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ["Chrome"],
    singleRun: true,
    concurrency: Infinity
  });
};
```

Karma Test (whole spec)

```
import { TestUtils } from "./test-utils.js";
import "../src/my-component.js";
describe("just test if it was rendered", () => {
  it("first try (using TestUtils)", async () => {
    const { shadowRoot } = await TestUtils.render("my-component");
    expect(shadowRoot.querySelector("#mydiv")).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it("second try (using fixture)", async () => {
    const el = await fixture.load("<my-component></my-component>");
    expect(el.success).to.be.false;
  });
});
```

Whole project: [all files](https://github.com/jimisdrpc/basic-vanilla-webcomponent)

Comment: Can u provide your spec file ? Basically the declaration part n all

Comment: I edited my question and added the whole suite with all specs (only two). The second one is exactly what I have pasted originally. I am wondering what are you looking for? Are you expecting something like beforeEach method? Well, here is all my suite and you can clone it from https://github.com/jimisdrpc/basic-vanilla-webcomponent/blob/master/test/my-component.test-without-openwc.js.